# Steeper motor control using ATmega32

Tags: avr, atmega, stepper-motor, proteus, atmel-studio

I was trying to control a stepper motor using ATmega32. i am using AVR studio 4.But, it is not working perfectly at simulation at Proteus. The 4 input signals for motor driver pin IN1, IN2, IN3 and IN4 are blinking without any sequence.  My code is following -

```
.include "m32def.inc"         

.DEF TEMP = R16
.DEF COUNTER = R17
.DEF _STACK = R18


.ORG $0000  

LDI TEMP, 0XFF
OUT DDRB, TEMP  

LDI _STACK,LOW(RAMEND)   ;SETUP STACK POINTER
OUT SPL, _STACK          ;SO CALLS TO SUBROUTINES
LDI _STACK,HIGH(RAMEND)  ;WORK CORRECTL
OUT SPH,_STACK




LABEL1:
LDI TEMP, 0b00000001
OUT PORTB,TEMP 
RCALL PAUSE

LDI TEMP, 0b00000010
OUT PORTB,TEMP 
RCALL PAUSE

LDI TEMP, 0b00000100
OUT PORTB,TEMP 
RCALL PAUSE

LDI TEMP, 0b00001000
OUT PORTB,TEMP 
RCALL PAUSE

RJMP LABEL1



;----------------;
;DELAY ROUTINE   ;
;----------------;
PAUSE:
LDI COUNTER, 2
PLUPE:
NOP   
 DEC COUNTER              
  BRNE PLUPE
   RET
```

[image: Proteus simulation design]

Comment: I've never used Proteus but your delay is very short, assuming it tries to run the code at full speed maybe the GUI isn't being updated quickly enough.

Comment: We posted at the same time, but you can answer your own question if you think it might help future visitors. It's better than just posting the answer as a comment, because the question still looks unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it. I changed the delay routine like this -

```
PAUSE:
LDI R17, 0X02
WAIT1:
LDI R20, 0X02
WAIT:
DEC R17
BRNE WAIT

DEC R20
BRNE WAIT1

RET
```